# Array deep copy and shallow copy

Tags: java, arrays, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm learning deep copy and shallow copy.

If we have two arrays:

```
int[]arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
int[]arr2={1,2,3,4,5};
```

*Question*: Both arrays point to the same references `[1][2][3][4][5]`.

What will happen if I change `arr1[2]`?Does it changes `arr2[2]`?

When we pass an array (random array, not necessarily `arr1` or `arr2`) from main into a method the compiler makes a **shallow** copy of the array to the method, right?

**If** the Java compiler was re-written to make and send a **deep** copy of the array data to the method.
What happens to the original array in the main? I think the original array may change according to the method and pass back into the main. I am not sure.

Comment: what is the result when you tried it?

Comment: No, it won't change it.

Comment: Both arrays don't point to the same thing. The way you initialized them, you created two separate arrays that happen to start out with the same contents. Primitives are values. `int[] arr1={1,2,3,4,5}; int[] arr2=arr1;` might make for a more interesting experiment.

Comment: think `int i = 1` if someone do a `i++`, does every 1 ever used in the program become 2?

Comment: Hints: 1) Do your tests using classes instead of primitive types. 2) Do your tests using immutable classes as `Integer` and `String` and mutable classes like `StringBuilder`.

Comment: By the way, your first questions are trivial things to test. If you don't feel like creating and compiling files [just do it online](https://ideone.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: Both arrays point to the same references [1][2][3][4][5].

Not exactly. Your arrays have identical content. That being said, as per your initialization, they data they are using is not *shared*. Initializing it like so would however:

```
int[]arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
int[] arr2 = arr1
```

> What will happen if I change arr1[2]?Does it changes arr2[2]?

As per the answer to the above question, no it will not. However, if you were to change your initialization mechanism as per the one I pointed out, it would.

> When we pass an array (random array, not necessarily arr1 or arr2)
>   from main into a method the compiler makes a shallow copy of the array
>   to the method, right?

Your method will receive a location where to find the array, no copying will be done.

> If the Java compiler was re-written to make and send a deep copy of
>   the array data to the method. What happens to the original array in
>   the main? I think the original array may change according to the
>   method and pass back into the main. I am not sure.

If you were to create a deep copy of the array and send it to your method, and your method will work on that copy, then, the original array should stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

Initalization of an array with values will always allocate new memory.
For "int[]arr1 ={1,2,3,4,5};"
The jvm will count the length of the initialization array and allocate the required amount of  space in the memory. In this case jvm allocated memory for 5 integers.
when you do "int []arr2={1,2,3,4,5}", the same thing happens again ( jvm allocates memory for another 5 integers).
Thus changing arr1[2] will not reflect arr[2].

```
arr1[2]=10;
 System.out.println(arr2[2]); // this will still print 3
```

If you wanted arr2 to point to the contents of arr1, you should do this:

```
int []arr2=arr1;
```

This would be a shallow copy. This makes an array reference object containing the same value as arr1. Now if you do :

```
arr1[2]=10;
System.out.println(arr2[2]); //this will print 10.
```

Now, if you want to do a deep copy of an array( Instead of duplicate initialization as you did), the right command would be:

```
int arr2[] = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);
```

This will behave like the first scenario ( your code - Changing arr1 will not affect arr2).

Answer (score 0):

Because you have primitive types, you create independent arrays. To demonstrate deep and shallow copy:

```
MyObject a = new MyObject("a");
MyObject[] first = new MyObject[] {a};
MyObject[] second = new MyObject[] {a};
a.setName("b");
System.out.println(second[0].getName());
second[0].setName("c");
System.out.println(first[0].getName());
```